# Missing CR char in binary email attachment in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code to send a binary file as an email attachment in Java.  The code works in that is does send the file.  However, in the file that is received any hex value of $0d either deleted or converted to $0a.  Since the file is a binary file not a text file the received file is incorrect.  Any suggestions please?

Rgds,
Helen

```
String fileAttachment = "command.cmd";
Session session = 
  Session.getInstance(props, null);
// Define message
MimeMessage message = 
  new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(
  new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(
  Message.RecipientType.TO, 
  new InternetAddress(to));


 message.setSubject(emailSubject);

// create the message part 
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = 
  new MimeBodyPart();

//fill message
messageBodyPart.setText("Hi");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// Part two is attachment
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource source = 
  new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
   System.out.println("Sending");

messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(
  new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileAttachment);
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


// Put parts in message
message.setContent(multipart);

// Send the message
Transport.send( message );
```

Comment: You should probably add more tags, because this isn't plain Java. At least the Java 7 API docs don't list any MimeMessage class.

Comment: Read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#encodebinary

Answer (score 3):

Binary attachments should really be encoded in a way that their non-printable characters are gone. The most obvious way to do that coming to mind would be BASE64 encoding.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for the really quick answer.  Problem solved by adding the line

      messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");